# Move down to the next row of filtered data vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have the sheet like this:

[Picture given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08Mkc.png)

All I want to is that, I can move down the next row and show its value.
I already have the code:

```
Sub test()

'Select the first row.

MsgBox Sheet1.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 3).Value

'Then move down to the second row of filtered data.

'Code

End Sub
```

Can someone suggest how to finish my sub above?

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try implement/adapt the following:

[image]

```
Sub VisRows()

Dim rng As Range, lr As Long
With Sheet1 'Change accordingly
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("B2:B" & lr)
    'Apply your filter
    For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Debug.Print cl.Value
    Next cl   
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I wonder: The loop always goes from up to down, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes this specific way of looping indeed does

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help. Hehe.